# Creating div dynamically but tinyMce isn't getting loaded for the dynamically created div

Tags: jquery, html, asynchronous, dynamic-loading, asynchronous-javascript

My html is

```
<body>
<section class="section">
<textarea id="template">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <img title="TinyMCE Logo" src="//www.tinymce.com/images/glyph-tinymce@2x.png" alt="TinyMCE Logo" width="110" height="97" />
    </p>

    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!</h1></textarea>
</section>

  <button class="btn">Click</button>
```

My JS looks like this.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         var temp = `  <textarea id="template">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <img title="TinyMCE Logo" src="//www.tinymce.com/images/glyph-tinymce@2x.png" alt="TinyMCE Logo" width="110" height="97" />
    </p>

    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!</h1>
  </textarea>`;
         $(".btn").on("click",function(){
            //  $(".section").append($("#template").html());
             $(".section").append(temp);
            //  $(".section").append(temp:String):tinymce.dom.DomQuery;
         });
     });
 </script>
```

My TinyMce code

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

As you can see in this image. On second click the tinyMce editor isn't loading. Can someone please help me in this? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Where in your code are you initializing tinymce? Please post the full relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the above code :

I made a custom function which wraps the tinyMce code

```
function addTiny() {   
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
```

}

And in the JS :

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        addTiny();
         $(".btn").on("click",function(){
                 $(".section").append("<br><textarea></textarea>");
                 addTiny();
             });
 });
 </script>
```